Question About Approximating the Variance of the Sample Mean for an AR(1) Process
$
\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\newcommand{\ol}[1]{\bar{#1}}
\newcommand{\Cov}{\on{Cov}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\on{Var}}
$
Problem Statement: Suppose that the time series data $\{x_i:i=1,\dots,N\}$
are generated from an $\on{AR}(1)$ process with parameter $\alpha.$
Show that the variance of their sample mean can be approximated
as follows for large $N,$
$$\Var\!\left(\ol{X}\right)\approx\frac{\sigma^2}{N}\!
\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)\!.$$
This is Problem 4.1 in The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction with R, 7th Ed., by Chris Chatfield and Haipeng Xing.
My Work So Far: So the $\on{AR}(1)$ process with parameter $\alpha$ we write down as
$$X_t=\alpha X_{t-1}+Z_t.$$
The sample mean is, of course, given by
$$\ol{X}=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i.$$
Now the variance of this sample mean we cannot compute simply by adding the
variances of the individual terms, because they are dependent. First, let's
start at $X_1$ and ratchet it up:
$$X_k=\alpha^{k-1}X_1+\sum_{m=0}^{k-2}\alpha^m Z_{k-m},\quad k=2,\dots,N.$$
Now then, we wish to compute:
\begin{align*}
\Var\!\left(\ol{X}\right)
&=\Cov\!\left(\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^NX_i,\frac1N\sum_{j=1}^NX_j\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N^2}\!\left[\Cov(X_1,X_1)
+2\sum_{j=2}^N\Cov\!\left(X_1,X_j\right)
+\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N\Cov(X_i,X_j)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{N^2}\,\Bigg[\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{1-\alpha^2}+
2\sum_{j=2}^N\Cov\!\left(X_1,
\alpha^{j-1}X_1+\sum_{m=0}^{j-2}\alpha^m Z_{j-m}\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad+
\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N
\Cov\!\left(
\alpha^{i-1}X_1+\sum_{m=0}^{i-2}\alpha^m Z_{i-m},
\alpha^{j-1}X_1+\sum_{m=0}^{j-2}\alpha^m Z_{j-m}\right)\Bigg].
\end{align*}
The $Z_t$'s are
independent. So this computation becomes
\begin{align*}
 \Var\!\left(\ol{X}\right)
 &=\frac{1}{N^2}\,
\Bigg[\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{1-\alpha^2}+
 \frac{2\sigma_Z^2}{1-\alpha^2}\sum_{j=2}^N\alpha^{j-1}
 +2\sum_{j=2}^N\sum_{m=0}^{j-2}\alpha^m \Cov(X_1,Z_{j-m})\\
 &+
 \sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N
 \Bigg\{\frac{\alpha^{i+j-2}\sigma_Z^2}{1-\alpha^2}+
 \alpha^{i-1}\sum_{m=0}^{j-2}\alpha^m\Cov(X_1,Z_{j-m})
   +\alpha^{j-1}\sum_{m=0}^{i-2}\alpha^m\Cov(X_1,Z_{i-m})\\
   &\qquad\qquad\qquad+\sum_{m=0}^{i-2}\sum_{n=0}^{j-2}\alpha^{m+n}
      \Cov(Z_{i-m},Z_{j-n})\Bigg\}
\Bigg].
\end{align*}
Now we work on the expression:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^{i-2}\sum_{n=0}^{j-2}\alpha^{m+n}\Cov(Z_{i-m},Z_{j-n})
&=\sum_{p=2}^i\sum_{q=2}^j\alpha^{i+j-(p+q)}\Cov(Z_p,Z_q),
\end{align*}
where $p=i-m$ and $q=j-n.$ This expression simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p=2}^{\min(i,j)}\alpha^{i+j-2p}\sigma_Z^2
&=\alpha^{i+j}\cdot\sigma_Z^2\sum_{p=2}^{\min(i,j)}\alpha^{-2p}\\
&=\alpha^{i+j}\cdot\sigma_Z^2\,\frac{1-\alpha^{2-2\min(i,j)}}{\alpha^2(\alpha^2-1)}.
\end{align*}
So much for the last term. For the two middle terms with covariances
of the form $\Cov(X_1,Z_{j-m}),$ note that
$2\le j-m\le j$ as well as $2\le i-m\le i.$ We can certainly assume
$X_1$ is independent of these higher $Z_t$'s, so those covariances are zero.
Note also that
$$\sum_{j=2}^N\alpha^{j-1}=\frac{\alpha^N-\alpha}{\alpha-1}.$$
Hence, we have that
\begin{align*}
\Var\!\left(\ol{X}\right)
&=\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{N^2}\left[\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2}
+\frac{2}{1-\alpha^2}\cdot\frac{\alpha^N-\alpha}{\alpha-1}
+\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N
\left\{
 \frac{\alpha^{i+j-2}}{1-\alpha^2}
   +\alpha^{i+j}\cdot
       \frac{1-\alpha^{2-2\min(i,j)}}{\alpha^2(\alpha^2-1)}
\right\}
\right].
\end{align*}
We keep moving forward:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N\frac{\alpha^{i+j-2}\,\sigma_Z^2}{1-\alpha^2}
&=\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{\alpha^2(1-\alpha^2)}\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N\alpha^{i+j}\\
&=\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{\alpha^2(1-\alpha^2)}\cdot
  \frac{\alpha^2(\alpha^N-\alpha)^2}{(\alpha-1)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sigma_Z^2(\alpha^N-\alpha)^2}{(1+\alpha)(1-\alpha)^3}.
\end{align*}
Now assuming $N>2,$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N\alpha^{i+j}\frac{1-\alpha^{2-2\min(i,j)}}{\alpha^2(\alpha^2-1)}
&=\frac{1}{\alpha^2(\alpha+1)(\alpha-1)}\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=2}^N
\alpha^{i+j}\left(1-\alpha^{2-2\min(i,j)}\right)\\
&=\frac{\alpha^{2N}-2(\alpha+1)\alpha^N+\alpha(\alpha N+2)-N+1}{(\alpha-1)^3(\alpha+1)}.
\end{align*}
Now then, we can plug these results back into the expression for the variance,
and take the limit as $N\to\infty.$ We do this in Mathematica, with the result
that for large $N,$
$$\Var\!\left(\ol{X}\right)
\approx\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{N(1-\alpha)^2}.$$
This is not the result hoped for, but it is very similar.
My Question: Where have I gone wrong?

I think the textbook's answer is wrong (and your answer is correct, though your derivation may be simplified a little bit by recognizing $\gamma(h) = \sigma^2\frac{\alpha^h}{1 - \alpha^2}$).  You should be able to verify this by running some simulation.

I think the book may be using different notation from your proof (it would be strange if it were wrong about a simple fact like this in a 5th edition)
Write $\sigma^2_X$ for the marginal variance of $X$. Then (see eg)
$$\sigma^2_X=\frac{\sigma^2_Z}{1-\alpha^2}$$
so
$$\frac{\sigma^2_Z}{N(1-\alpha)^2} = \frac{\sigma^2_X(1-\alpha^2)}{N(1-\alpha)^2}=\frac{\sigma^2_X(1-\alpha)(1+\alpha)}{N(1-\alpha)^2}=\frac{\sigma^2_X(1+\alpha)}{N(1-\alpha)}$$
so perhaps the book meant the observable $\sigma^2_X$ rather than the model's $\sigma^2_Z$ by $\sigma^2$

Oh, interesting! The book's problem statement is exactly how I have it: there's no subscript on the $\sigma^2,$ nor any clarification as to which variance the $\sigma^2$ is referring. Your explanation would certainly fit what's going on, here. Many thanks!

Yep, I think you're right. On page 80-1, the author mentions this approximation, and in context, the $\sigma^2/N$ for independent $X$'s is compared to this expression. So it has to be $\sigma_X^2.$
